# SecondaryNamenode and MapReduce jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

maybe that's a silly question... but anyway...

How would I understand that the secondary namenode does something (I mean it works), I must configure It to do something?

Also jobs in MapReduce run in parallel by default, I mean what you program in MR always run in parallel?

I made these questions because I have to proof (I have an project to do) that jobs on hadoop run in parallel.

Thanks you in advance.

P.S: Sorry for my bad english, and hope that I was understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yon, when you configure Hadoop you put `hostname` of some machine into the `/conf/masters`. This is where your SNN will run. You could go to the terminal of that machine and issue JPS. This will show you all the java processing running currently. You should be able to see  SecondaryNameNode along with other processes. Something like this :

```
apache@hadoop:~$ jps
21615 TaskTracker
21268 SecondaryNameNode
21014 DataNode
27656 HRegionServer
21362 JobTracker
19908 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
17643 Jps
27364 HMaster
28451 Main
27194 HQuorumPeer
29811 RunJar
20744 NameNode
```

To cross check you could change this to some other machine and see the effect. Alternatively you could check it via the SNN port, which is 50090 by default. Does it make sense?

And when you run a MR job, you could open the `mapreduce webUI` by pointing your web browser to `jobtracker_machine:50030`. Here you can see a list of all the jobs you are running(or which you have run previously) along with the total number of mappers/reducers created for a particular job. You can click on a job and it will show you all the mappers and reducers running currently on your cluster. You can see the progress of each mapper/reducer over there. All these mappers/reducers run in parallel in different machines. To verify that you could click on each mapper and it will show you the machine where that particular mapper/reducer is running along with the % completion of each mapper/reducer.

HTH

Comment: thank you man... I have three nodes, 1 master (master is slave too) and two slaves, on `/conf/masters`of all nodes I have putted only master's hostname. You mean that I have to put also slaves hostnames...?

Comment: You are welcome. No. Hostnames of slave machines are required only in /conf/slaves. As per your current setting SNN is running on your master machine. /conf/masters is required for specifying SNN alone.

Comment: so I'm ok with that... I have another question for you man, cause I'm relatively newbie on hadoop and still learning, which is the difference between the pseudo mode and the full mode of cluster? The pseudo mode is the same with single mode    Thanks again!

Comment: For instance, if you put the hostname of slave1 into the /etc/masters file then SNN will run on slave1 machine.

Comment: No prob. In pseudo mode all the hadoop daemons(NN, SNN, JT, DN, TT) will run in different JVMs but on a single machine, while in a fully distributed cluster all these daemons will run in different JVMs and on different machines.

Comment: I have installed hadoop on VBox, on one computer, so I am in pseudo mode?

Comment: Yes. Looking at your setting it seems to be a pseudo cluster. Otherwise you could have standalone cluster as well wherein all the daemons run together inside a single JVM instance on a single machine. In this mode you don't have HDFS, instead local FS is used.

Comment: Sorry for my foolishness, but I ask you cause I want to clear it in my mind. On VBox I have three different machines (1 master and 2 slaves), so that's pseudo mode without HDFS or full mode?

Comment: Nothing like that. You are actually running a fully distributed cluster on VMs. You have 3 different virtual machines running all the hadoop daemons in their own JVMs.